# Getting Bad Request 400 while requesting for access token from authorization code Reddit API

Tags: python, bearer-token, reddit-access-token

I'm trying to use the reddit API to pull text data for a project, but I can't get the OAuth access token. Instead of responding with the access token, the response just says bad request.

Here's my code:

```
data={'grant_type':'authorization_code','code':'authcode which I got from the get request before','redirect_uri':'https://www.google.com/'}
r=requests.post('https://www.reddit.com/api/v1/access_token',data=data,auth=('client ID','client Secret'),headers={'User-Agent':'Rishi'})
print(r.text)
```

this what I'm getting

> {'message': 'Bad Request', 'error': 400}

Triple checked the personal use script and secret, and so I'm struggling to think of what's wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: What headers has your response (add `print(r.headers)` to check that)?

Comment: 400 is often used as a catchall response that just means "you did something wrong".  Often there's no way to tell exactly what the problem is.

Comment: APIs often expect to receive their data input via json.  Do you know if the reddit API expects json?  Your code does not send json.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/), I don't see any url that matches `/api/v1/access_token`.  Where did you get that url?